# Replace content of block on submit with content of json object

Tags: json, twig, yaml, mailchimp

I am trying to embed a custom mailchimp form in a `twig` such that when the user clicks the `submit` button, the response from mailchimp replaces the content in the div.

I am using Gantry5 and I have successfully implemented the form, and when the user clicks the submit button, I get a response from the mailchimp server.

The problem I am having is that rather than replacing the content in the block, it is refreshing the page and then displaying the json object in raw format.

The `twig` is below:

```
{% extends '@nucleus/partials/particle.html.twig' %}

{% block particle %}

  {% if particle.title %}<h2 class="g-title">{{ particle.title|raw }}</h2>{% endif %}

  {% if particle.headtext %}<div class="g-newsletter-headtext">{{ particle.headtext|raw }}</div>{% endif %}

    <div id="mc_embed_signup" class="g-newsletter {{ particle.class|e }}">

      <form class="g-newsletter-form validate" id="mailchimp-subscribe" action="//{{ particle.baseurl|e }}" method="POST">

        <input type="hidden" name="u" value="{{ particle.uuid|e }}">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ particle.lid|e }}">

        <div id="mergeTable" class="mergeTable">
          <label for="MERGE0">Email Address <span class="req asterisk">*</span></label>
          <input class="g-newsletter-inputbox required email" type="email" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" name="MERGE0" id="MERGE0" size="25" value="" placeholder="{{ particle.inputboxtext|raw }}">
          <input type="submit" value="{{ particle.buttontext|raw }}" name="submit" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="g-newsletter-button button {{ particle.buttonclass|e }}">
        </div>

        <input type="hidden" name="ht" value="{{ particle.htvalue|raw }}">
        <input type="hidden" name="mc_signupsource" value="hosted">

      </form>
    </div>

<script src="/javascripts/application.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async defer>
  $('#mailchimp-subscribe').submit(function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET", // GET & url for json slightly different
        url: "//{{ particle.baseurl|e }}-json?c=?",
        data: $this.serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        error: function(err) { alert("Could not connect to the registration server."); },
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.result != "success") {
                // Something went wrong, parse data.msg string and display message
            } else {
                // It worked, so hide form and display thank-you message.
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
  });
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

The response I get from the server is below:

```
{"result":"success","msg":"Almost finished... We need to confirm your email address. To complete the subscription process, please click the link in the email we just sent you."}
```

What I want to do is either replace the content in the block with a formatted response or open the formatted response in a modal.

I tried adding `data-uk-lightbox data-lightbox-type="iframe"` to the `button` (I am using UIKit" and a modal opens up, but I only get a `loading` indicator that never refreshes, with even the unformatted json response.

Please advise.

Answer (score -1):

have you tried this?

```
e.preventDefault()
```